# Search for special characters in a string in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the below code wherein I am trying to search for special characters and the length of the string. Should the condition fail, an error note should be written to the host. I am using PowerShell 2.0. The code checks for the string length, but it is not able to check for any special character.

```
$chk = $user_logon.Output_Value
if($chk.length -gt 64 -or $chk -notmatch '[^a-zA-Z0-9]')
{
  Write-Host "Error - The Value ""$chk"" is greater than 64 bits or it contains a special character" -BackgroundColor "White" -ForegroundColor "Red";
}
```

I also tried -

```
if($chk.length -gt 64 -or $chk -notmatch "^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$")
```

which has worked. But I would like to have the condition which checks for all the special characters barring an underscore "_" which can be a part of $chk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace `$chk -notmatch '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'` with `$chk -match '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'`

Comment: Thanks. It solves my case where it matches a string with no alphabets or digits. I was also looking forward to a case where I could match a string with no special characters barring an underscrore.

Comment: The case - if($chk.length -gt 64 -or $chk -match "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]") has worked. Not sure if its the best approach. Thanks.